# Custom Confirm Box Throws Unexpected Error

Tags: javascript

I have the code below. It is supposed to be use like the `confirm()` function, but also be customizable with CSS. There is a function called `confirmDelete(event.target, ${bookID}, ${x})`, but when I call this function the is an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. But if i remove the last parameter (`${x}`) it can run without an error.

The `deleteBookCard(x, bookID)` is called when I click the delete button from my HTML. The x is equal to `event.target`.

```
function deleteBookCard(x, bookID) {
   let confirmBox = `
       <div class="confirm-screen">
           <div class="confirm-box">
               <div class="delete-msg">Are you sure you want to delete "<span>${myBooks[bookID - 1].title}</span>"?
               </div>
               <div class="confirm-cancel-btn">
                   <button class="confirm-btn" onclick="confirmDelete(event.target, ${bookID}, ${x})">Confirm</button>
                   <button class="cancel-btn" onclick="confirmDelete(event.target, ${bookID}, ${x})">Cancel</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   `;
   
   x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", confirmBox);
}

function confirmDelete(x, bookid, y) {
   if (x.textContent === "Confirm") {
       console.log(y);
   } else {
       console.log("NOT DELETED");
   }
}
```

Comment: May be the value of x is null or is jquery is not able to convert it into a jquery object.

Comment: @Reporter I dont think thats true, because x is event.targer.. Also im using vanilla JS

Comment: Well if `ix` is `event.target` what do you expect the result of `\`confirmDelete(event.target, ${bookID}, ${x})\`` to be? Problably something like `confirmDelete(event.target, 1234, [Object object])` which doesn't seem to be too valid ...

Comment: @leech may be the error raised in method `deleteBookCard()` and not in `confirmDelete()`.

Comment: What are the values of `x` and `bookID` that you pass into `deleteBookCard()`? (You may be hitting one of the main flaws of building HTML as a string, which is that it's very easy to produce broken HTML)

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `x.parentNode ...` and inspect the string contained in `confirmBox`

Comment: Using the google chrome console, i got this `<button class="confirm-btn" onclick="confirmDelete(event.target, 2, [object HTMLElement])">Confirm</button>`. Why is it [object HTMLElement]?

Comment: @derpirscher is right - this cannot work, since `x` references an object and you are dealing with a string literal here. The object will be serialized to `[Object object]` or something similar, which causes the syntax error. You should pass a boolean (`true` or `false`) to `confirmDelete()` which indicates what button has been clicked.

Comment: @majusebetter The passed thrid parameter is not used in method `confirmDelete()`. so it should does'nt matter what kind of value it is.

Comment: @Reporter it does not matter whether it is actually used. If you have a string literal containing HTML with event handler attributes, the object will be serialized to a string representation. For JavaScript `someFunction(1234, [Object HTMLDivElement])` is not valid syntax. BTW: The error occurs in function `deleteBookCard()`

Comment: @Reporter but the call of the method is invalid. Because if you define `onclick="..."`  the browser tries to execute whatever is between the double quotes as javascript. but `confirmDelete(event.target, 2, [object HTMLElement])` is not valid javascript ...

Comment: Guys I found another way to achieve what I wanted, without including the third parameter

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, the solution cannot work since `x`  references an object and you are dealing with a string literal here. The object will be serialized to `[Object object]` or something similar, which causes the syntax error. You can only use primitive types as parameters here.

You could pass a boolean (`true` or `false`) to `confirmDelete()` which indicates what button has been clicked.

```js
const myBooks = [
  {
    title: '1984',
    author: 'George Orwell'
  }
];

function deleteBookCard(x, bookID) {
   let confirmBox = `
       <div class="confirm-screen">
           <div class="confirm-box">
               <div class="delete-msg">Are you sure you want to delete "<span>${myBooks[bookID - 1].title}</span>"?
               </div>
               <div class="confirm-cancel-btn">
                   <button class="confirm-btn" onclick="confirmDelete(${bookID}, true)">Confirm</button>
                   <button class="cancel-btn" onclick="confirmDelete(${bookID}, false)">Cancel</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   `;
   
   document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", confirmBox);
   // x.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", confirmBox);
}

function confirmDelete(bookid, confirmed) {
   if (confirmed) {
       console.log(bookid);
   } else {
       console.log("NOT DELETED");
   }
}

deleteBookCard(document.body, 1);
```